# Uber API Request error message: "Method not supported for this endpoint.",

Tags: android, api, request, uber-api

I want to implement UBER API into my android application.

I am using [this link for the API](https://api.uber.com/requests) and [this link for the sandbox](https://sandbox-api.uber.com/requests)

In the header Authorization:

```
Bearer <token>
```

In the parameter:

```
start_latitude,start_longitude
```

I am following the tutorial, but I am getting an error message:

```
{"message":"Requires at least one scope. Available scopes: ","code":"unauthorized"}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Quick google and it comes up with this:
https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/tutorials/api/introduction
The key things you need to know about OAuth can all be found in your application dashboard.

client_id and client_secret available on the settings tab.
redirect_uri and **scope you specify on the authorizations tab.**

Think you need to have a look inside the application dashboard

Comment: on the Authorization tab GENERAL SCOPES are activated

Answer (score 0):

How do you authorize your users? I'd recommend to check out this tutorial: https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/guides/authentication/introduction#oauth-20

Your URL should include the `scope=request`parameter since you want to access the /v1/requests endpoint. Also keep in mind that you can use the request scope without having privileged access for up to 5 developers. You can maintain these in your developer dashboard.